# Replacing sys.argv with docopt

Tags: python, string, replace, sys, docopt

I'm working on incorporating some string replacements and currently arguments are passed to my script using `sys.argv[i]`. I'd like to replace sys with docopt, but I've found the documentation relatively unclear so far.

The way my code currently works is

```
filename.py -param_to_replace new_param_value
```

(I can also include multiple params to replace)

This then gets processed by

```
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    for i in range((len(sys.argv)-1) / 2):
        params[sys.argv[1+2*i].split('-')[1]] = float(sys.argv[1+2*i+1])
```

where params is the name of a set of defined parameters.

I think I should be able to get this to work with docopt, but so far what I have is more like

```
"""Docopt test
Usage:
  filename.py --param_name1 <val> --param_name2 <val>

  filename -h | --help
  filename --version

Options:
  -h --help     Show this screen.
  --param_name1 Change some param we call param_name1, all other params changed in similar way


"""
from docopt import docopt


if __name__ == '__main__':
    arguments = docopt(__doc__, version='filename 1.0')
    print(arguments)
```

But this doesn't pass anything and seems to be the end of the details provided in the official documentation. Does anyone with more familiarity with docopt know how to more effectively pass the command line arguments? Or should I replace sys.argv with "arguments" after this?

Thanks!

Comment: ...do you have a question?

Comment: Realized I didn't make my question clear and have since tried to clear that up - sorry!

Comment: *"doesn't work"*?! [mcve], please. Have you tried looking at the docs your `argparse` version generates as an example?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - have again updated question after a long time not posting on any stackexchanges. The documentation generated by my sys.argv usage produces the result of replacing each specified parameter (current format is params = ['name': value, 'name': value]). I'm hoping to get docopt to do the same, so would the usage of "arguments" in the above be apt in place of "sys.argv"?

Comment: What is `__doc__`?  `docopt` like other argument parsers uses the `sys.argv` list (usually behind the scenes).  Your original code parses that list directly.  What does `arguments` show?

Comment: As pointed by @hpaulj i don't think that docopt would fit your usecase (as it parse the docstring to build the `arguments` object you are trying to make). With such a docstring it expect a first options to be given with the name `param_name1` (only <val> is supposed to be a variable), idem for `param_name2`. You should stick to parse the list directly (and you can still write a nice docstring!)

Comment: Show us an actual script invocation and output.  Make sure you use the format that you specify in the `docopt` creation.

Comment: @hpaulj I've been trying to undertand what the __doc__ in docopt means, because as far as I've been able to see, it's just been __doc__ in all uses. I'll tack on a use case to the question since it's too long to include in comments. Although if it doesn't meet my use case, I'd be happy to know that since that's valuable information in and of itself.

Comment: @mgc to be sure I understand, since the format of the commands easily parsed, parsing directly is preferable?

Comment: I know `argparse` well, and know about `docopt` only because some posters think is it much easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I thought I would return to this since I realized I never closed the topic and post an answer. The proper way to pass the arguments is as below:

```
"""Usage: filename.py [--arg1=N] [--arg2=N] 

Options:
    --arg1=N passes arg1
    --arg2=N passes arg2
"""

 from docopt import docopt 
 arguments = docopt(__doc__,version='')
 print arguments[--arg1] #This is to print any argument or pass it through
```

It seems there was just some problem with usage, which is cleared up in the code here.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `docopt` (which is great anyway), if you just want to build a dict of `-param`: `value` as docopt would have returned you can do this with a dictionary comprehension (i guess in a more comprehensible way than what your are currently doing):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        args = sys.argv[1:]
        assert len(args) % 2 == 0
        arguments = {args[i][1:]: args[i+1] for i in range(0, len(args), 2)}
        print(arguments)
```

Then test it:

```
In [12]: runfile(
             'test.py', wdir='/home/mgc',
              args='-param_to_replace1 new_value1 -param_to_replace2 new_param_valu2')

{'param_to_replace2': 'new_param_valu2', 'param_to_replace1': 'new_value1'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just realized what the `__doc__` is doing (see my comments).

When the module is loaded, the initial triple quoted string is assigned to its `__doc__` variable.  Normally this is the documentation that various 'help' packages can use.  Functions and classes also have `__doc__`.  For `docopt` use it is supposed to model the `help` display of the commandline parser.

The

```
arguments = docopt(__doc__, version='filename 1.0')
```

line passes this`__doc__` string to the `docopt` function (or class).  That deduces what arguments you want to accept, parses the `sys.argv`, and returns a dictionary, `arguments`.

In your example, the usage line is:

```
filename.py --param_name1 <val> --param_name2 <val>
```

I would expect that if you called the script with

```
filename.py --param_name1 foo --param_name2 bar
```

that `arguments` will be a dictionary that looks like:

```
{'param_name1':'foo', 'param_name2':'bar'}
```

and `arguments['param_name1']` should return 'foo'

Your current code apparently tries to parse an input like

```
filename.py -foo 2.323 -xxx 1.23
```

and perform

```
params['foo'] = 2.323
params['xxx'] = 1.23
```

I expect that the `docopt` version would produce an error with this input, but I don't know the details of how well it handles errors.

[Better solution than if __name__ == '__main__' twice in Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33956594/better-solution-than-if-name-main-twice-in-python-script) is a longer example of using `python` `docopt`.

### argparse version

Here's an `argparse` script which behaves, I think, like your `sys.argv` parsing.  It defines a set of `argparse` arguments based entries in the `params` dictionary, and should return a compatible dictionary.

```
import argparse

params = {'foo':None, 'bar':None, 'test':0}

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
for key in params:
    name = '--'+key
    default = params[key]
    if default is None:
        parser.add_argument(name)
    else:
        # could be more elaborate on setting type
        parser.add_argument(name, default=default, type=float)

parser.print_help()
print(params)
print(vars(parser.parse_args([]))) # no arguments, should == params
args = parser.parse_args()  # test the sys.argv
print(args)   # namespace
print(vars(args))  # dictionary equivalent
```

producing:

```
1033:~/mypy$ python stack34956253.py --foo 124 --test 323.3
usage: stack34956253.py [-h] [--test TEST] [--foo FOO] [--bar BAR]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help   show this help message and exit
  --test TEST
  --foo FOO
  --bar BAR
{'test': 0, 'foo': None, 'bar': None}
{'test': 0, 'foo': None, 'bar': None}
Namespace(bar=None, foo='124', test=323.3)
{'test': 323.3, 'foo': '124', 'bar': None}
```

This might work the same way:

```
argparse_help = parser.format_help()
arguments = docopt(argparse_help, version='filename 1.0')
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are having a problem with your docopt grammar. For me, it helps to work out the docopt grammar using the [web docopt tool](http://try.docopt.org). The setup makes it easy to iterate quickly over a grammar and see if it will produce a structure that is useful for my program.

I put your grammar in [here](http://try.docopt.org/?doc=Usage%3A%0D%0A++filename.py+--param_name1+%3Cval%3E+--param_name2+%3Cval%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A++filename+-h+%7C+--help%0D%0A++filename+--version%0D%0A%0D%0AOptions%3A%0D%0A++-h+--help+++++Show+this+screen.%0D%0A++--param_name1+Change+some+param+we+call+param_name1%2C+all+other+params+changed+in+similar+way%0D%0A%0D%0A&argv=--param_name1+foo+--param_name2+bar) with the arguments `--param_name1 foo --param_name2 bar` and got this result:

```
{
  "--param_name1": "foo", 
  "--param_name2": true, 
  "<val>": "bar"
}
```

In the first part, you specified: `Usage: filename.py --param_name1 <val> --param_name2 <val>`. Note that you used `<val>` in 2 distinct positions, which means only the 2nd value is populated. In the second part, you again specified: `Options: --param_name1`, which is redundant because you already specified the same `--param_name1` in the usage section. An argument should be in one but not both sections.

[Here](http://try.docopt.org/?doc=Usage%3A%0D%0A++filename+--old%3D%3Cold%3E+--new%3D%3Cnew%3E%0D%0A&argv=--old%3Dfoo+--new%3Dbar) is a simplified grammar:

```
Usage:
  filename --old=<old> --new=<new>
```

The result of parsing with `--old=foo --new=bar` is:

```
{
  "--new": "bar", 
  "--old": "foo"
}
```

Or remove the switch names altogether and just use positional arguments. [This](http://try.docopt.org/?doc=Usage%3A%0D%0A++filename+%3Cnew%3E+%3Cold%3E...%0D%0A&argv=bar+foo+baz) makes it easier to anticipate the multiple arguments for what you want to replace.

```
Usage:
  filename <new> <old>...
```

With `bar foo baz` arguments, this is the parsed structure:

```
{
  "<new>": "bar", 
  "<old>": [
    "foo", 
    "baz"
  ]
}
```

I just [blogged](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2016/01/better-command-line-programs-with-docopt/) about how much I like docopt, so I hope you get over the initial hurdle of understanding.